# Prove trigonometric identity for $\tan^2(\theta/2)$

Tags: trigonometry

I've been at this for a couple of days (3-4 hours total now), and am feeling lost:

$$(1)\ \tan^2(\frac{1}{2}\theta) = \frac{\tan(\theta) - \sin(\theta)}{\tan(\theta)+\sin(\theta)}$$

I'm aware that 
$$(2)\ \tan^2(\frac{1}{2}\theta)=\frac{1 - \cos(\theta)}{1 + \cos(\theta)} = \frac{\left(\frac{1 - \cos(\theta)}{2}\right)}{\left(\frac{1 + \cos(\theta)}{2}\right)}$$

And have been working towards solving the right-hand-side of the first identity listed into something along the lines of the right-hand-side of the second identity...though, I've been having no success.

Any thoughts?

**Edit**

For the sake of clarification, I'm also aware of the double angle rules and how they are used to obtain $\tan^2(\frac{\theta}{2})$; my issue is understanding the *connection between those rules* and what exists on the RHS within equation $(1)$. Apologies for any confusion on this.

Comment: From the second line, cancel the 2's in the denominator and multiply the top and bottom by $\mathrm{tan}(\theta)$.

Comment: If you replace $\tan\theta$ on the right-hand side by $\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}$ and fool around a little, you will get something familiar.

Comment: @AndreNicolas: believe it or not, that's a large portion of what I've been trying. I always end up with something like $\frac{\sin(\theta) - \sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)}{\cos(\theta)}$ in the numerator, and $\frac{\sin(\theta) + \sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)}{\cos(\theta)}$ in the denominator. It's from there that I feel lost.

Comment: @aboutblank: You're close! You have "stuff-over-cosine" in the numerator, and "otherstuff-over-cosine" in the denominator, so those cosines cancel. (Why?) This leaves "stuff-over-otherstuff". Factoring the "stuff" and the "otherstuff" will lead to more cancellation, and you're practically there!

Comment: The first top is $\sin\theta(1-\cos\theta)$.  The second top is $\sin\theta(1+\cos\theta)$. Divide.

Comment: That really was right under my nose. Thank you both for the tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{\tan(\theta) - \sin(\theta)}{\tan(\theta)+\sin(\theta)}=\frac{\sin(\theta)/\cos\theta - \sin(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)/\cos\theta+\sin(\theta)}=\frac{1/\cos\theta - 1}{1/\cos\theta+1}=\frac{1-\cos\theta }{1+\cos\theta}$$
You can use the double angle rule to get
$$\frac{1 - \cos(\theta)}{1 + \cos(\theta)}=\frac{1 -1+ 2\sin^2(\theta/2)}{1 + 2\cos^2(\theta/2)-1}=\frac{\sin^2(\theta/2)}{\cos^2(\theta/2)}=\tan^2(\theta/2)$$

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but I failed to mention something in my original post. I've updated my question accordingly.

Comment: @aboutblank is it clear now, or i did not understand what you want?

Comment: Yes, thanks much!